# How to align the numbers of an ordered list to right?

Tags: html, css

Consider code below:

In the output, The list items are indeed in the right, but the number are not. How to also align the number at the right position?

```css
ol {
  width: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<ol style="text-align:right;">
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Grape</li>
  <li>Watermelon</li>
  <li>Strawberry</li>
  <li>Blueberry</li>
  <li>Raspberry</li>
  <li>Kiwi</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the rtl direction's attribute to `ol` tag: `dir="rtl"`.

Comment: Thank you a million time, also this is one of the fastest response I got))))